# UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate not launching his methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface

I created a category of UIViewController with a bunch of methods. One of this methods shows a custom UIViewController similar to an UIAlertController.

I'm using Objective-c and this is how is my code set

.h File

```
@interface UIViewController (ActivityViewController) <UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate>

   -(void)showAlert;

@end
```

.m File

```
-(void)showAlert{

   CustomAlertViewController *alert = [[CustomAlertViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomAlertViewController"                                                                              bundle:nil];

   self.transitioningDelegate = self;
   alert.transitioningDelegate = self;
   alert.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
   [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - Custom Transitioning Delegate

- (UIPresentationController *)presentationControllerForPresentedViewController:(UIViewController *)presented
                                                  presentingViewController:(UIViewController *)presenting
                                                      sourceViewController:(UIViewController *)source
{
  (...)
}

- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented
                                                              presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting
                                                                  sourceController:(UIViewController *)source
{
  (...)
}


- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForDismissedController:(UIViewController *)dismissed
{
  (...)
}
```

As you can see, I set the category as the UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, but my problem is that the delegate methods are not launched, and the custom transition is not happening, just the default one.

In a separate test project, everything worked fine.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

So my code is right, but the problem was that inside the .m file there was two different implementations (one for the category and another for a subclass) and the delegate methods were set inside the wrong implementation.

Changed to the category implementation and everything worked fine.